# Wordpress how to view open mysql connections?

Tags: wordpress

I keep getting `MySQL - server has gone away`, `internal server errors` and `503 -server not found`.  I assume this is due to too many connections to the database and connections not closing.  I want to pinpoint, which queries of plugins are causing this.  Is there a function or a plugin i can use to view which mysql connections are open?  I haven't got access to mysql on server, so i need within wordpress.

Comment: Do it the rhinoceros way,disable plugins based on intuition

Comment: The errors are random, they can't be duplicated.  So i want to see which queries are taking the longest or not closing.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26164/how-can-i-find-the-source-of-slow-queries-in-wordpress